# How make "check out date" autofill the following day of "check in date" using pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, html, pickadate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').pickadate();
$('.datepicker2').pickadate();
</script>

<form action="#" method="get">
    Check In Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"><br>
    Check Out Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is just the basic form of html that I made and I have no idea on how to make the autofill work on pickadate.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $( "#submit" ).click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#datepicker').pickadate();
        $('#datepicker2').pickadate();

    }
});

    <form action="#" method="post">
        Check In Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"><br>
        Check Out Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="datepicker2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
```

[Date Picker JS API](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/). There is a passage called events. You just can add a small onSet function, which will set the date to the second datepicker, for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datepicker').pickadate(
    onSet: function(context) {
        // Maybe set the min date for the second datepicker.
        $('.datepicker2').pickadate(
            min: new Date(document.getElementByClassName("datepicker").value),
        );
        // maybe increment the value by one too...
    }
);

$('.datepicker2').pickadate();
</script>

<form action="#" method="get">
    Check In Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"><br>
    Check Out Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```